# Laravel cant change my status in my databse using the toggle button?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-8

Im using a toggle button switch:

```
<td><input data-id="{{$user->id}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" {{ $user->statusBol ? 'checked' : '' }}></td>
```

Here is my script with the ajax:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.toggle-class').change(function(){
        var statusUser = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0; //1 active, 0 inactive
        var user_id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                url: 'changeUserStatus',
                data : {'statusUser': statusUser, 'user_id': user_id},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('Success')
                }
            });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my web.php code:

```
Route::get('changeUserStatus', [SupAdController::class, 'changeUserStatus'])->name('changeUserStatus');
```

Then my SupAdController.php:

```
public function changeUserStatus(Request $request){
    $users = User::find($request->user_id);
    $users->statusBol = $request->statusUser;
    $users->save();
}
```

The toggle button can be clicked but the status on the database wont change.

Comment: dd($request->all()); in your controller and check what you are getting in 'statusUser'

Comment: Check browser devtools - does the network request happen?  Is the payload right?  What is the server response?  BTW [convention is to use POST when changing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get).

Comment: Nothings happening after I tried dd($request->all());